# How to pass child class into controller in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a parent class and its child in my application model.
And have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/page")
public String postMethod(Model model, Parent obj, BindingResult result) {
     // do something
}
```

but I want it to be able to handle instances of the child class, that was posted by form.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object of required type as an implicit model attribute:

```
@ModelAttribute("parent")
public Parent createChild(@RequestParam("type") String type) {
    if ("foo".equals(type)) return new Foo();
    else if ("bar".equals(type)) return new Bar();
    else return null;
}
```

Since Spring doesn't remember type of the object passed to the form automatically, you need to do it yourself, by adding a hidden form field whose value specifies type of the object (a `type` field in the example above).

Another option is to avoid creating object from scratch by storing it in a session. It can be configured using `@SessionAttributes` annotaton, see [15.3.2.9 Specifying attributes to store in a session with @SessionAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib).

Comment: Could you also explain me the meaning of "type" parameter, please

Comment: when I'm trying to write "@RequestParam("type") String type" server gives me 404 error (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()), but I need some way to distinguish what object was sent. Should this type parameter be hardcoded in my form or it can be passed automatically by spring?

Comment: Yes, this is a solution to my problem! thnx!